# Using JDialog with Tabbed Pane to draw different pictures

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jdialog, diagrams

I am using NetBeans, and I have a class that extends to JDialog, inside that Dialog box I have created a Tabbed Pane. The Tabbed Pane contains 6 different tabs, with 6 different panels of course. What I want to do is when I click on the different tabs, a diagram is supposed to be drawn with the paint method.

My question is how can I draw on the different panels with just one paint method in another class being called from the Dialog class?

Here is my code for the Dialog class:

```
package GUI;    

public class NewJDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog{

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJDialog
     */
    public NewJDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel5 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel6 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel7 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 466, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 242, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("FCFS", jPanel1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 466, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 242, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("SSTF", jPanel2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 466, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 242, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("LOOK", jPanel3);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
        jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
        jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 466, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 242, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("LOOK C", jPanel4);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel5Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel5);
        jPanel5.setLayout(jPanel5Layout);
        jPanel5Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 466, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel5Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 242, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("SCAN", jPanel5);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel6Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel6);
        jPanel6.setLayout(jPanel6Layout);
        jPanel6Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 466, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel6Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 242, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("SCAN C", jPanel6);

        getContentPane().add(jTabbedPane1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jLabel1.setText("Distancia:");

        jLabel2.setText("___________");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel7Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel7);
        jPanel7.setLayout(jPanel7Layout);
        jPanel7Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel7Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel7Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addContainerGap(331, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel7Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel7Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel7Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel7Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        getContentPane().add(jPanel7, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the dialog */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                NewJDialog dialog = new NewJDialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel6;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel7;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    // End of variables declaration  
}
```

This is another class that I have created for the paint method:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Lienzo {

    private int width = 5;
    private int height = 5;
    private int y = 5;
    private int x = 0;
    private int x1 = 0;

    public Graphics Draw(Graphics g, int[] pistas) { 
        //Im not sure if this is the correct way to do it
        //The diagram gets drawn according to values from an array
        //The array is not always the same thats why I used the different Panels

        for (int i = 0; i < pistas.length; i++) {
            x = pistas[i];
            x1 = pistas[i + 1];

            g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
            g.drawString(Integer.toString(x), x, y);
            g.drawLine(x, y, x1, y);

        }
        return g;
    }
}
```

I hope you guys understand what I am trying to do with my program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make a "GraphPane" that extends something like `JPanel`.  In this class I would provide a means by which you can supply the array information for graph.  I would take the logic from your `draw` method and add inside the `paintComponent` method of the `GraphPane`.

I would then add an instance of this `GraphPane` to each tab, seeding each one with appropriate array data.

Depending on where the data is coming from, you might also need to pass the array data to the dialog when you create it